# How to receive row Id when row is selected

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using v-data-table and I want get row Id when a row selected.

this is my code

```
<v-data-table
          item-key="id"
          v-model="selected"
          show-select
          :headers="headers"
          :items="users">
</v-data-table>
```

Something that give me when I select a row:

```
[
{id:2 , name:"kevin" , age : 25 }
]
```

Something I need it to be:

```
[2]
```

Comment: Just map the `selected` array to IDs: `selected.map(x => x.id)`

Comment: I think maybe there is better way , maybe with props

Comment: Not sure what could be the better way here.

Answer (score 0):

Upon using the v-data-table you can use the v-model in the table.
And then you can watch for your selected array and get the field you want from it.

```
 <v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="desserts"
  :single-select="singleSelect"
  item-key="name"
  show-select
  class="elevation-1"
>
```

As you see the selected is an array I defined in the data section.

```
 data () {
return {
  singleSelect: false,
  selected: []
}
```

Comment: possibly you didn't get me . i want to get arrays of ids not arrays of objects .

Comment: you can use computed to get the the ids using ".map" function.

Comment: i'm looking for better way

Comment: Better than a computed? I don't think it's possible.
`v-data-table` component can provide you the selected item, but I do not think it can give you a "variartion" of that item.
A computed prop (as @Basselalshayeb suggested) on the `selected` value (just as @tony19 wrote) is probably the best way to achieve what you want